# Check if a product exists on table using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I have a this variable `List<ProductViewModel> viewModel`. I want to check if some of the products on that variable already exists on PRODUCTS table.

`ProductViewModel` declaration is:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I have tested this predicate:

```
Expression<Func<PRODUCTS, bool>> predicate =
    p => (p.LAW == (byte)LawTypes.Korea) &&
        !viewModel.Any(item => item.ProductCode == p.PRODUCT_CODE);
```

And this one:

```
Expression<Func<PRODUCTS, bool>> predicate =
    p => (p.LAW == (byte)LawTypes.Korea) &&
        !viewModel.Select(x => x.ProductCode).Contains(p.PRODUCT_CODE);
```

When I do this with both predicates:

```
if (_dbSet.Where(predicate).Count() == 0)
```

I get the following exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'MyProject.Web.API.Models.ProductViewModel'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

`PRODUCTS` is:

```
public class PRODUCTS
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public byte LAW { get; set; }
}
```

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're assuming that your linq using the expressiontree has access to your local variable `viewModel`:

```
Expression<Func<PRODUCTS, bool>> predicate =
p => (p.LAW == (byte)LawTypes.Korea) &&
    !viewModel.Any(item => item.ProductCode == p.PRODUCT_CODE);
```

You will pass this expression to linq queries, which have no idea at all what you mean with `viewModel`.

You should probably make a connection between `ProductViewModel` and `Product` by using `ProductCode` as foreignKey:

```
public class PRODUCTS
{
public int Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ProductViewModels")]
public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
public byte LAW { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ProductViewModel> ProductViewModels {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can write your expression as following:

```
Expression<Func<PRODUCTS, bool>> predicate =
p => (p.LAW == (byte)LawTypes.Korea) &&
    !p.ProductViewModels.Any();
```

Just make sure you make the right relations between product and viewmodel, I assumed it is one-to-many. You will have to define your foreign key in database too if it's database first.